# Why is it wrong to create list using x = list[0:8] in python?

Tags: python

Why is it wrong to create a list using this?

```
x = list[0:8]
```

To create a list between 2 values, is this the only way to do it?

```
list(range(0, 8))
```

Thanks

Comment: `list[0:8]` will only create a range of numbers if is `list` a range of numbers. What's `list`?

Comment: what is wrong with ```range()``` ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate there is no list to start with. I get it now! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nilsinelabore , `[x:y]` means slice the list from the index x to y-1 and you can only slice it if the list exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong because it doesn't give you the result you want.

If you write this:

```
x = list[0:8]
```

You're telling Python: take the existing variable called `list`, select the 0th element up to the 8th element (i.e. the first 8 elements, lists start at 0) and assign the result to the variable `x`.

The `[0:8]` part is called a 'slice' and it works on many types of variables you can access by index. As you're applying the slice to `list`, Python interprets that as something indexable and tries to 'slice' it - that doesn't work unless you actually defined a list called `list`, which is not recommended as it 'shadows' the `list` type that is standard Python.

You're not telling Python: generate the numbers 0 through 7, turn it into a list and assign the result to the variable `x`, which is what this means:

```
x = list(range(0, 8))
```

Note that this is enough for most cases, but it won't get you a list, but the range itself, so don't do this if you actually need a list:

```
x = range(0, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> x = list[0:8]
> ```

You use this syntax to splice an existing list, named `list` and assign it to the variable `x`, you don't actually generate a new list. If you don't have `list` defined, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
x = list[0:8]
print(x)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    x = list[0:8]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

It's wrong, because it doesn't work. You use `[x:x]` to select a slice of items from a list, not to generate a list. You could instead use range, or use list comprehension.

```
x = list(x for x in range(0, 100))
print(f"There are {len(x)} items in the list")
```

result

```
"There are 100 items in the list"
```

Slice it and get the last 50 items, `[50:]` indicates we start at the 50th index, and not putting anything after the `:` means go until the end. Inversely you can do `[:80]` and it will start at the start and go up to the 80th index, which is the same as `[0:80]`.

```
half = x[50:]
print(f"There are {len(half )} items in the list")
```

result

```
"There are 50 items in the list"
```